# How to display nested comments properly in html/django template language

Tags: html, css, django

I have a threaded comment system in django and at this time i have this code to check for any related comments:

```
<ul>
{% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
    <li>{{ children }}</li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

This works but i have a css design where every comment is in a buble shaped form so the list item icon is on the outside which seems weird and ugly. I would like to remove this icon the li creates but dont know if its possible, and if not, how do i display the proper indentation for each sub comment ? I dont seem to find anything about this on google. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS applied to `ul`:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

to hide `<li>` dots. You also may want to change `margin` and `padding` for `<li>`.

Other option is to use `<div>` and `<span>` instead of `<ul>` and `<li>` in your template (but proper CSS changes may be needed).

Comment: Thanks for answering finelord. I thought about the div but then i would need a different div width for each sub comment wouldn it? It would be preferable to use divs and spans but i dont know how i would implement a different indentation for each sub comment.

Comment: Need to know more details to answer about div and span realization. In general not a big deal what to use. Try list-style and list-style-type CSS as a start point. If it's solve your problem that will be the final solution.